# REST API url page takes forever to load

Tags: rest, dhtmlx

I'm using REST API to populate my data to my DHTMLXGantt chart. It took around 1 minute to display. Even when I try to access the API URL it took forever to load, why is this happening? The code is confidential so I can't paste it here, but has several `if else` and `for` loop condition in it and i assuming that's one of the reason, Is there anyway i can optimize the loading speed? any help is much appreciated. Does pagination helps to populate the data into smaller chunks? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You could copy the basic configuration to a sample project in order to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In its current form we can only speculate on the reasons why your API is slow.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the rendering time of the Gantt chart on the page try next ways:

- To disable the rendering of single cells and leave just rendering of rows (set the show_task_cells option to 'false')
- To set the background image for the timeline area instead of rendering the actual lines (set the static_background option to 'true') (PRO functionality)
- To enable the dynamic loading (set the branch_loading option to 'true')
- To increase the scale's step (set the scale_unit to "month" or "year")
- To decrease the range of displayable dates (use the start_date and start_date options)
- To remove progress bars from the tasks (set the show_progress option to 'false')
- To enhance the speed of the scale rendering (enable the smart_scales option in case it's disabled)